# USPTO patent search database no longer secure over web SSL https

Tags: uspto, search, prior, art, security

Does anyone know how to do a safe query of the: USPTO Patent Application Full-Text and Image Database (AppFT)?

When queries to the database essentially go across the web either to your VPN host or your client browser on your PC.  Previous to 2017, it WAS secured utilizing SSL.

Quick search web address - http://appft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html

Without inadvertently revealing IP when narrowing down the search to final patent #'s and classifications ?  Many time one must get very specific to identify prior artwork or patent #'s.

Is no longer hosted at USPTO using any type of SSL (https://) security, it appears to be open text from the host end.  No amount of VPN protection from the client can secure the connection (end to end) either.

Google patents does host all their patent database on SSL server,  But then again its google,  They probably already have the entirety of your IP before you thought of it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might try  [Espacenet](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/),  [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/) or [PatentScope](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/search.jsf) - all are https

Comment: +1 for The Lens.